# Why I'm having a Traceback error using pip in Win 10?

Tags: python, windows, pip, spyder, traceback

I'm Carlos, recently I had move to windowns 10 and I started to install all my stuff.

When I tried to install spyder via pip I had had the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.ui import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress import HIDE_CURSOR, SHOW_CURSOR
ImportError: cannot import name 'HIDE_CURSOR' from 'pip._vendor.progress' (c:\users\carto\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.py)
```

I don't know what to do, It would be wonderful if you could help me to fix this problem

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to reinstall pip

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pip-hide-cursor-error/8174

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Two pieces of advice: (1) Please use Anaconda instead of pip because it's better supported and stable. If you decide to continue with pip, you're basically on your own (i.e. you won't receive support from us); and (2) Please use Python 3.7 instead of 3.8 because the last one still has some problems on Windows.